# Find cumulative average based on column values in spark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

This is my dataframe:

```
# +--------+--------+------+------+----------+------------+-------------------+-------------+
# |Location|   Month| Brand|Sector| TrueValue|PickoutValue| month_in_timestamp|TotalSumValue|
# +--------+--------+------+------+----------+------------+-------------------+-------------+
# |     USA|1/1/2021|brand2| cars2|16383104.2|    16666667|2021-01-01 00:00:00|   16383104.2|
# |     USA|2/1/2021|brand2| cars2|26812874.2|    16666667|2021-01-02 00:00:00|   43195978.4|
# |     USA|3/1/2021|brand2| cars2|      null|        null|2021-01-03 00:00:00|   43195978.4|
# |     USA|1/1/2021|brand3| cars3|      75.6|        70.0|2021-01-01 00:00:00|         75.6|
# |     USA|2/1/2021|brand3| cars3|      77.1|        70.0|2021-01-02 00:00:00|         76.4|
# |     USA|3/1/2021|brand3| cars3|      73.1|        70.0|2021-01-03 00:00:00|         75.3|
# |     USA|4/1/2021|brand3| cars3|       0.0|        45.3|2021-01-04 00:00:00|         56.4|
# |     USA|5/1/2021|brand3| cars3|       0.0|        67.9|2021-01-05 00:00:00|         45.1|
```

Here Im deriving TotalSumValue column by calculating the cumulative sum of "brand2" rows and cumulative average of "brand3" rows.
Im having data for the months Jan to Dec for all different brands.

While calculating the cumulative average for brand3, in TrueValue column, I have "0.0" values for the upcoming months. Currently, even "0.0" is also considered for calculating the cumulative average. Instead, I need to consider only the months having values other than "0.0".

So, my expected dataframe is:

```
# +--------+--------+------+------+----------+------------+-------------------+-------------+
# |Location|   Month| Brand|Sector| TrueValue|PickoutValue| month_in_timestamp|TotalSumValue|
# +--------+--------+------+------+----------+------------+-------------------+-------------+
# |     USA|1/1/2021|brand2| cars2|16383104.2|    16666667|2021-01-01 00:00:00|   16383104.2|
# |     USA|2/1/2021|brand2| cars2|26812874.2|    16666667|2021-01-02 00:00:00|   43195978.4|
# |     USA|3/1/2021|brand2| cars2|      null|        null|2021-01-03 00:00:00|   43195978.4|
# |     USA|1/1/2021|brand3| cars3|      75.6|        70.0|2021-01-01 00:00:00|         75.6|
# |     USA|2/1/2021|brand3| cars3|      77.1|        70.0|2021-01-02 00:00:00|         76.4|
# |     USA|3/1/2021|brand3| cars3|      73.1|        70.0|2021-01-03 00:00:00|         75.3|
# |     USA|4/1/2021|brand3| cars3|       0.0|        45.3|2021-01-04 00:00:00|          0.0|
# |     USA|5/1/2021|brand3| cars3|       0.0|        67.9|2021-01-05 00:00:00|          0.0|
```

This my my code block:

```
windowval=(Window.partitionBy('Location','Brand').orderBy('month_in_timestamp')
               .rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0))

df = df.withColumn('TotalSumValue',
         F.when(F.col('Brand').isin('brand2'), F.sum('TrueValue').over(windowval)) \
         when(F.col('Brand').isin('brand3'), F.avg('TrueValue').over(windowval)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed a dot (well, I missed it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69176407/calculate-cumulative-sum-and-average-based-on-column-values-in-spark-dataframe/69176510#69176510) as well but you could have found the problem, or ask within comments ;-) )

```py
windowval=(Window.partitionBy('Location','Brand').orderBy('month_in_timestamp')
               .rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0))

df = df.withColumn('TotalSumValue',
           F.when(F.col('Brand').isin('brand2'), F.sum('TrueValue').over(windowval)) \
           .when(F.col('Brand').isin('brand3'), F.avg('TrueValue').over(windowval)))
```

Comment: @Christophe- I had added a dot in my code :) Thanks.. But my concern is 0.0 should not be considered while calculating the cumulative average.. Im not able to solve that..

Comment: I tried to propose you an option, but too many conditions came to me (what about if you have 0 values for brand 1 or 2, what if you intend to add conditions afterwards...) so I do not thing your approach is correct. You could separate calculations with all your conditions in an intermediate dataframe, then make a left outer join to your dataset - but you need to have a key pivot column or a primary key... I'm afraid this would lead to too many options to propose one solution

Comment: True.. Makes sense.. Let me try to simplify the existing dataframe. Thanks !!